# I'm using for-each loop and want to highlight a single row in LWC using onmouseover but only the topmost row in the loop is getting highlighted

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css, lightning-design-system, html

In this code every time I'm hovering the mouse on a record the topmost row in the component is getting highlighted instead of the corresponding row on which the mouse is hovered. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

HTML file snippet

```
<template for:each={actions} for:item="action">
            <div class="slds-p-vertical_xxx-small box" key={action.Id} id={action.Id} onmouseover={addColor} onmouseout={removeColor}>
                <div class="slds-p-left_medium">
                    {action.Name}
                </div>
            </div>
</template>
```

JS File snippet

```
addColor() {
    this.template.querySelector('.box').classList.add('highlight');
}

removeColor() {
    this.template.querySelector('.box').classList.remove('highlight');
}
```

CSS File

```
.highlight {
background-color: rgb(243, 242, 242);
```

}

Screenshot

[image: E]

Here I've my mouse pointed on 'Action 3' record but the 'Action 1' is getting highlighted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

querySelector gets only the first matching item. You probably want:

```
addColor(event) {
    event.target.classList.add('highlight');
}

removeColor(event) {
    event.target.classList.remove('highlight');
}
```

Comment: thanx for answering but as per your suggestion, the class is getting applied to only the current div and not to the whole parent div. What I want is that the 'highlight' class is added/removed to/from the whole parent div and not the individual child div.

Comment: @HimanshuSrivastava You can use `event.target.closest('sometarget')` to select a parent element to modify as well.